# onclick function not executing to change image

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following codepen I'm trying to change the image of an image with id="chrome" using JavaScript but it does not appear to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix. Thank you in advanced.

The first image has an id of chrome and when clicked I'm trying to change the image.

https://codepen.io/centem/pen/NgKEmG

Here is the js I'm using.

```
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("chrome").src == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("chrome").src = "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("chrome").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png";
    }
}
```

Basically, for the first row that has an chrome icon I would like to change it to an x image upon click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<img onclick()="changeImage()">` to `<img onclick="changeImage()">`

Answer (score 0):

First off, change the `<img onclick()="changeImage()"` to `<img onclick="changeImage()"`. That doesn't solve your problem if you want to do it for multiple users, as each one of the chrome images needs it's own ID for the function to work on more than one logo.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo. When defining an inline `onclick` you have written:

```
<div onclick()="changeImage()"></div>
```

It should be:

```
<div onclick="changeImage()"></div>
```

**See snippet below:**

```js
function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("chrome").src == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("chrome").src = "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("chrome").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png";
        }
    }
```

```css
img {
   height: 25px;
      padding-right: 4px;
  }
  li {
   margin: 4px;
      clear: both;
  }
  li:nth-child(odd) { 
   background: #f0f0f5; 
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Username<span class="pull-right">
          <img onclick="changeImage()" id ="chrome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img id="firefox" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
          <img id="ie" src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>
    
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onclick()="changeImage()";.... Use **onclick="changeImage()"**.....Remove **"()"** bracket in onclick function

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error in your HTML code. `onclick` is not a function, it is an HTML attribute, so you don't call it like a function by adding parentheses to it.

You only to that to the value of the `onclick` attribute, which is JavaScript syntax.

The correct code is:

```
<img onclick="changeImage()">
```

Here is a working version of your code pen: https://codepen.io/pahund/pen/XgWVQx